# Upgraded node and npm via nvm, but old node is still used for global packages

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, nvm

I've been using node 9.3.0 for a long time, but I recently migrated to 10.12.0. Everything went fine, when I do `node -v` and `npm -v` I get the correct versions:

```
Paul-Bergs-Macbook:node paulrberg$ node -v
v10.12.0
Paul-Bergs-Macbook:node paulrberg$ which node
/Users/paulrberg/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/node
Paul-Bergs-Macbook:node paulrberg$ npm -v
6.4.1
Paul-Bergs-Macbook:node paulrberg$ which npm
/Users/paulrberg/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/npm
```

Howeven, when I'm trying to run any npm command, the old version is used. That is:

```
Paul-Bergs-Macbook:node paulrberg$ npm i truffle -g
/Users/paulrberg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/truffle -> /Users/paulrberg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
+ truffle@4.1.14
added 81 packages from 311 contributors in 1.715s
```

And:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
/Users/paulrberg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/lib
└── truffle@4.1.14
```

Not sure if this is some bash code still pointing to the last version, but I can't seem to find any proof for that. Running `env` and checking for `9.3.0` environment variables yields no result.

What I did so far:

- Delete node 9.3.0 with `nvm uninstall 9.3.0`
- Do a fresh install of nvm after deleting it and rebooting the computer
- `nvm reinstall-with-packages`
- Deleted `~/.nvmrc` and set `10.12.0` in there afterwards
- Check if I have an overlapping node from homebrew and I don't 
  What could the problem be?

Comment: Try to uninstall 9 version of node

Comment: I did that several times via `nvm uninstall 9.3.0`. When I do `npm install truffle -g` or any npm command, 9.3.0 is installed again.

Comment: Question: is version 9.3.0 installed again, or is the directory created?

Comment: The actual node 9.3.0 seems to be installed in the nvm directory. When I run `nvm ls` again I get both 10.12.0 and 9.3.0 after installing a global npm module (or actually running any command with npm).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After a few hours of painful Unix debugging, I realised the problem was that I set a prefix in `npm config`:

```
prefix = "/Users/paulrberg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0"
```

To fix this, make sure to unset the prefix by doing:

```
npm config rm prefix
```

This is [mentioned](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), albeit not necessarily shining in the nvm doc

> If you have an ~/.npmrc file, make sure it does not contain any prefix
>   settings (which is not compatible with nvm)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you might need to run `nvm reinstall-packages`

https://github.com/creationix/nvm#migrating-global-packages-while-installing

which says

---

> Migrating global packages while installing
>   If you want to install a new version of Node.js and migrate npm packages from a previous version:

`nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node`

> This will first use "nvm version node" to identify the current version you're migrating packages from. Then it resolves the new version to install from the remote server and installs it. Lastly, it runs "nvm reinstall-packages" to reinstall the npm packages from your prior version of Node to the new one.
>
> You can also install and migrate npm packages from specific versions of Node like this:

`nvm install 6 --reinstall-packages-from=5`
`nvm install v4.2 --reinstall-packages-from=iojs`

---

The other "solution" is not to use global packages. Particularly when using nvm and not being able to be sure that the global package is for the "current" version it can be better to install locally and use `npx` to run the local command

truffle installs a `truffle` command to ./node_modules/.bin when you `npm install` it so you can `npx truffle` to run the local one instead of `truffle` to run the global one

---

edit:

another thing to check is that `node -v` and `nvm current` don't necessarily report the same version.

I wonder if `nvm current` would report v9.3 for you?

[image]

ah, yep, on my machine I can install truffle globally in a different location than `node -v` reports

[image]

```
 > node -v
v9.5.0
 > nvm current
system
 > nvm use v8
Now using node v8.4.0 (npm v5.3.0)
 > node -v
v8.4.0
 > nvm current
v8.4.0
 > npm install -g truffle
/Users/pauldambra/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin/truffle -> /Users/pauldambra/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
+ truffle@4.1.14
added 81 packages in 4.364s
```

So you might be missing an `nvm use v10` command

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried `nvm reinstall-packages` with no luck. Thanks for the suggestion with `npx` but I'd still keep the global packages as they are now.

Comment: yeah, no worries, I've found npx less confusing when using nvm but only suggested as a workaround :) have added another possibility that lets me recreate your problem on my machine

Comment: I've already done `nvm use 10.12.0` multiple times. `nvm current` returns 10.12.0 this is def a quirky bug :/

Comment: crikey, it really is! hope you get it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that a more permanent solution is [this section](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#default-global-packages-from-file-while-installing) from the support docs.

> Default global packages from file while installing
>
> If you have a list of default packages you want installed every time you install a new version, we support that too -- just add the package names, one per line, to the file $NVM_DIR/default-packages. You can add anything npm would accept as a package argument on the command line.